# Using std::initializer_list constructor without creating ambiguities?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, initializer-list, type-deduction

I have a class called `Shape`, which can be initialized from any iterable, and a class called `Array`, which simply contains a `Shape`. However, I'm getting a compile error I can't explain when I try to initialize an `Array`:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    template<typename Iterator>
    Shape(Iterator first, Iterator last)
        : m_shape(first, last) {}

    template <typename Iterable>
    Shape(const Iterable& shape)
        : Shape(shape.begin(), shape.end()) {}

    template<typename T>
    Shape(std::initializer_list<T> shape)
        : Shape(shape.begin(), shape.end()) {}

private:
    std::vector<std::size_t> m_shape;
};

class Array
{
public:
    Array(const Shape& shape)
        : m_shape(shape) {}
private:
    Shape m_shape;
};

int main() {
    Shape s{0};       // ok
    Array a1({1, 2}); // ok
    Array a2({0});    // error
}
```

The compilation error appears on the second constructor of `Shape`:

```
prog.cxx:35:16:   required from here
prog.cxx:14:23: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘shape’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
         : Shape(shape.begin(), shape.end()) {}
                 ~~~~~~^~~~~
prog.cxx:14:38: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘shape’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
         : Shape(shape.begin(), shape.end()) {}
                                ~~~~~~^~~
```

I don't understand what is happening here. Why is the `Iterable` constructor called instead of the `initializer_list<T>` constructor? What's the difference between the `Shape` constructor with `{0}` and the `Array` constructor?

Comment: I can't reproduce; your code compile fine (no error in `s5` line) with my g++ 6.3.0 and with my clang++ 3.8.1 (I mean... if you correct `NDShape`, for the second constructor, in `Shape`, obviously). Which compiler are you using?

Comment: You are right, sorry. I simplified the code too much. The updated code should give you an error now. Thanks!

Comment: now I have an error but it's completely different from the one you reported; can you confirm the "no matching function for call to ‘cbegin(const int&) [...]" error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is ill-formed, but not for the reason gcc claims it is. When you write:

```
Array a2({0});
```

We do overload resolution over all the constructors of `Array` using the initializer `{0}`.

Option #1 is:

```
Array(Shape const& );
```

on which we would recurse into attempting to copy-initialize `Shape` with `{0}` which ends up invoking the `std::initializer_list<int>` constructor template due to preferential treatment of `std::initializer_list` during list-initialization.

However, that's just one option. Option #2 is:

```
Array(Array&& );
```

The implicit move constructor. To check if that's a candidate, we see if we can initialize `Array` with `{0}`, which basically starts over again. In this next layer, we see if we can initialize `Shape` with `0` (since we're one layer removed), and we *can* - that's your accept-all-the-things constructor template. This does involve two user-defined conversion sequences, but [that's ok for list-initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#7.sentence-3).

So we have two options:

- Option #1: `{0} --> Shape`
- Option #2: `0 --> Shape --> Array`

Neither is better than the other, so the call is ambiguous.

---

The easy fix is to add a constraint to your constructor template such that it actually is a range. This is generally good practice anyway, since you don't want `is_constructible_v<Shape, int>` to be true...

Comment: +1. Interestingly, one could remove option #2 by suppressing the conversion `Shape` --> `Array` by writing `explicit Array(const Shape&)`. Clang-5.0.0 (happy) and GCC 7.2 (complaining) [do not agree if that fixes the issue](https://godbolt.org/g/6ty5e7). Does it make sense to submit a bug report? Suppressing the conversion `int` --> `Shape` by declaring the corresponding constructor as `explicit` [works as expected](https://godbolt.org/g/nEB2vo) (and is simpler than adding constraints). You may want to add that single-argument constructors should always be considered as `explicit` candidates.

Comment: @Julius Yeah, I think that's a gcc bug. But `explicit` isn't really sufficient, since it's not like `Shape s(0);` is valid either - you do need the constraints anyway.